# A formalized definition of the linear operator $T$ such that $T(x^n)=x^{n(n+1)}$ over the unit interval, for every positive $n$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

If there are no mistakes in my specialization from a formula (if you are interested see the Appendix) involving a definite integral and the calculations that I did can be justified, one has $$\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}( x^n-x^{n(n+1)}) \right) \frac{dx}{\log x}=1,\tag{1}$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. See the definition of the Möbius function, if you need it, for example from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

I am interested to know how can I define the (linear) operator $T:S_1\to S_2$, being $S_1$ a set of good functions $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)x^n$ defined on an/the unit interval, and $S_2$ another good set (I presume that the image of our operator) by $$T\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)x^n\right):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)x^{n(n+1)}.\tag{2}$$

> **Question.** Can you provide me a formalized definition of $T$, and the sets of functions $S_1$ and $S_2$ that I need to set a definition with mathematical meaning in $(2)$? **Thanks in advance.**

**Rermarks and motivation:** 1) With [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) and this code written in Wolfram Language for a cutoff function, one can see a graph for the first factor inside the integrand of $(1)$

`plot sum mu(n)/n (x^n-x^(n(n+1))), from n=1 to 1000, for 0<x<1`

2) Then if have meaning all my remarks I believe that defining over an unit interval $$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n,$$ one can write $$\int_0^1(I-T)f(x)\frac{dx}{\log x}=1.$$

**Appendix:** I did my calculations to get $(1)$ using the first integral of page 537 from this nice article, for which there exist a free access from the AMS:

Jeffrey C. Lagarias,  *Euler’s constant: Euler’s work and modern developments*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **50** (2013).

Comment: If such operator $(2)$ was in the literature feel free to refer the literature instead of an answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Again, choosing $\mu(n)$ (the most complicated sequence you can find) is the best way to not understand what is happening.

Comment: Many thanks @Did

Comment: How would the existence of the linear operator $T$ help you?

Comment: All users, I'm sorry the right example that I tried to evoke is $$\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}( x^n-x^{n(n+1)-1}) \right) \frac{dx}{\log x}=1.$$ Thus $(1)$ is wrong. Many thanks and apologizes all users and to your @RobertIsrael

Comment: Many thanks Somos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take both $S_1$ and $S_2$ to be the space $H(\mathbb D)$ of functions $f$ analytic in the open unit disk $\mathbb D = \{z: |z| < 1\}$.  Note that the Maclaurin series of such a function converges absolutely to the function in the disk, and uniformly on compact subsets of it; conversely if the series converges absolutely at points arbitrarily close to $1$, the radius of convergence is $1$.  Moreover, $|z^{n(n+1)}| \le |z^n|$ so 
$T(f) \in H(\mathbb D)$.

EDIT: I don't see how you get your integral

$$ \int_0^1 (I-T)f(x) \dfrac{dx}{\log x} = 1 $$

I get $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^k - x^{k(k+1)}}{\log x}\; dx = \log(k+1) - \log((k(k+1)+1)  $$

and the partial sums $$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\mu(k)}{k} (\log(k+1)-\log(k(k+1)+1))$$

for $100 \le N \le 10000$ are all between $0.535$ and $0.868$.
Maple's numerical evaluation of the series is $0.717481715309322$.
The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au) and [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=.717481715309322&language=english&go=Search) find nothing for this.

Comment: Many thanks for your early response. I am going to study your answer.